# session value visible even after invalidate

Tags: java, session, struts2

Let me tell you about my situation:
1) I am using struts2.
2) I am using sessionmap to store the logged in user's name. So that i get "Hello Username" after login.
3) I have a logout button.
4) i have a method that handles this logout action. in that method i have sessionmap.invalidate();

5) This method, after invalidating directs to the initial login page.

Problem: when I click on the back navigation button i get redirected to the previous "logged in" page and the supposedly invalidated value (in my case the user name) is still there.

any clue what is to be done ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's from browser cache not from session.

Comment: any idea how I can clear the browser cache ?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=disable+browser+back+button&oq=disable+browser+back+button&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j0j69i60j0j69i60.3242j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi invalidate the session in your JSP or what ever page you use as view technology which uses Scriplets. It invalidate the session even when you  click on back button.

```
<% 
    /* use java code here and invalidate session based on a variable*/
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply force and redirect the user avoiding browser back button click, try this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
history.forward();
window.onunload=function(){};</script>
```